# network timeout problem?

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking

I don't know what kind of error is this.. I can't open my site anymore

```
Server Error in '/site' Application.
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

please help me.. tnx

Comment: Is your site on a shared server (shared with other sites) or on its own?

Comment: You did develop the site, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timeout expired (something took longer than it should).  Specifically, the timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the connection pool.  It turns out This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

(You're using Connection Pooling and probably not closing your connections.  After you are done with a `SqlConnection` or similar connection object, call `.Close()` on it)

Comment: Would this error not be more related to threadpooling in IIS than connections to the DB?

Comment: Check your code: you are leaving connections open.  Close them when you are finished, recompile, redeploy.

Comment: @Jon - no, there's nothing to do with IIS there: it's talking about connection pooling.  The fact that it's displayed in a web browser is simply because it's a web app

Comment: Help you how? The problem is, there are database connections being left open by your code.  The solution to that problem is, you need to close them.  That's the answer!!

Answer (score 3):

[10 Tips for Writing High-Performance Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx#S4)

**Connection Pooling**

Setting up the TCP connection between your Web application and SQL Server™ can be an expensive operation. Developers at Microsoft have been able to take advantage of connection pooling for some time now, allowing them to reuse connections to the database.

Always close your connections when you're finished with them. Do not trust the common language runtime (CLR) to clean up and close your connection for you at a predetermined time. The CLR will eventually destroy the class and force the connection closed, but you have no guarantee when the garbage collection on the object will actually happen.

To use connection pooling optimally, there are a couple of rules to live by. First, open the connection, do the work, and then close the connection. It's okay to open and close the connection multiple times on each request if you have to (optimally you apply Tip 1) rather than keeping the connection open and passing it around through different methods. Second, use the same connection string (and the same thread identity if you're using integrated authentication). If you don't use the same connection string, for example customizing the connection string based on the logged-in user, you won't get the same optimization value provided by connection pooling. And if you use integrated authentication while impersonating a large set of users, your pooling will also be much less effective. The .NET CLR data performance counters can be very useful when attempting to track down any performance issues that are related to connection pooling.
Whenever your application is connecting to a resource, such as a database, running in another process, you should optimize by focusing on the time spent connecting to the resource, the time spent sending or retrieving data, and the number of round-trips. Optimizing any kind of process hop in your application is the first place to start to achieve better performance.

Comment: This is plagarism to copy all that text. Just leave the link.

Comment: @Aliostad - i though so ..but it think its better to paste link + contenet so he can get more idea easily

Comment: Just bring a small snippet and make it as quotation. I will re-consider my downvote.